# How to use ionic Storage get?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Is this normal to call like this or what's the best usage because nothing else is working

```
this.storage.get('email').then((email) => {
this.storage.get('token').then((token) => {

  this.http.get('https://app.dev/clients.json?login='+email+'&client_token='+token)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        // we've got back the raw data, now generate the core schedule data
        // and save the data for later reference
        this.data = data;
        resolve(this.data);
      });
  });
});
});
```

I tried

```
data: any;
token: string;
phone:string;
constructor( private http: Http, public storage: Storage) {}


load() {

this.storage.get('token').then((token) => {
    this.token = token;

});
this.storage.get('phone').then((phone) => {
    this.phone = phone;
});   

  this.http.get('https://app.dev/clients.json?login='+this.phone+'&client_token='+this.token)
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(data => {
            // we've got back the raw data, now generate the core schedule data
            // and save the data for later reference
            this.data = data;
            resolve(this.data);
          });
      });
```

But this.phone = phone; is not assigned

I wish I could just call this.storage.get('phone') and no promises.

Comment: Able to just do `this.phone = this.storage.get('phone');`?

Comment: Nope its a promise.

Comment: What type of storage are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is returning a promise, then your first snippet of code would be the most common way.

I am using an older version of Ionic 2 (`2.0.0-beta.4`) that still uses .js so what I am suggesting may or may not be working for your version.

```
import {LocalStorage} from 'ionic-angular';

constructor(...){
  this.local = new Storage(LocalStorage);
  this.local.set("Key", "Key_Value");
}

buttonClick(){
  this.key = localStorage.getItem('Key');
}
```

This is currently how I am using Local Storage. Just a suggestion if you do not want to deal with promises.

Comment: Yeah, I had local storage but Ionic storage just support more storage engine. I think I will wait a bit more on how to get the best from storages.

Comment: I had to go with pure javascript localstorage. window.localstorage.getItem()